# Value-deviation pressure with RXJS

Tags: typescript, rxjs

I have an `Observable` that produces a fast infinite sequence of positive-integer values.

And I need to somehow replace it with sequence of value-change percents, for whenever outside a change-percent threshold, while within a certain interval window (in milliseconds).

**Code sample:**

```
function getPressurePercents(input: Observable, minChange: number, iw: number) {
   // return an observable that emits value-change percents that are outside
   // minChange percent value during any iw (interval window)
}

const obs = getPressurePercents(input, 0.5, 3000).subscribe(val => {
    // values in the input have changed by at least 0.5% in the last 3 seconds
    // value = value-change percent, Math.abs(value) >= 0.5
    // it is positive for value-percent increases, and negative for decreases
});
```

In the example above, I want to get an observable that emits value-change percent whenever input numbers show 0.5% change/deviation inside any 3-second window.

The purpose of this is to spot value-change pressure spikes, and get notified of all percents outside the threshold. Case in point: equity price changes too fast by too much (price spike).

IMPORTANT: It must work both up and down, i.e. a percentage drop inside a window is expected to emit a negative percent accordingly.

**SOLUTION**

I ended up with my own solution, implemented outside RXJS pipeline, but one that can be easily integrated into RXJS pipeline. It is much simpler and concise than pure RXJS solutions offered here previously. See my answer below.

Comment: I'm not completely clear on the desired behavior. Can you show  an example calculation with some numbers over a time period that shows the desired result?

Comment: @BizzyBob I ended up with my own solution in the end - see my answer. It shows the calculation logic you asked about.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was waiting for a fully functional RXJS solution, but there was none that I could use right away, so here's my 2 cents, a solution without RXJS, but one that can be easily combined with RXJS:

```
class SpikeDetector {

    private buffer: Array<{ ts: number, value: number }> = [];

    constructor(private change: number, private interval: number) {
    }

    next(value: number, spike: (change: number) => void): void {
        const ts = Date.now(); // timestamp
        const b = this.buffer; // abbreviation        
        while (b.length && ts - b[0].ts > this.interval) {
            b.shift();
        }
        b.push({ts, value});
        if (b.length >= 2) {
            const change = 100 * value / b[0].value - 100;
            if (Math.abs(change) >= this.change) {
                b.length = 0;
                spike(change);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Usage with RXJS:**

```
const sd = new SpikeDetector(0.5, 3000);

input.subscribe(value => {
    sd.next(value, change => {
        // value spike by >=0.5% within 3 seconds
    });
});
```

Or via an RXJS helper like below:

```
function changeSpike(input: Observable<number>, change: number, i: number) {
    const sd = new SpikeDetector(change, i);
    return input.pipe(switchMap(value =>
        new Observable<number>(obs => {
            sd.next(value, change => obs.next(change));
        })
    ));
}
```

**UPDATE**

[Here's a complete and much improved solution](https://gist.github.com/vitaly-t/e4475271ad08ee6879da756b31c068a0) that I use in my financial project, for detecting equity price spikes.

Answer (score 0):

I think solution may look something like this

- It correctly sends spike notification as soon as spike appears, without waiting any interval, but considering values from last `spikeIntervalMs`, so that we could instantly react to spikes
- When there is a spike wave, like when percent change is gradually increasing or decreasing, it sends only those spike notifications which are higher than maximum in this spike wave, until spike wave is over(we meet period without spike)

```js
export function getSpikedPercentChangeAbs$(
  value$: Observable<number>,
  spikePercentage: number,
  spikeIntervalMs: number,
): Observable<number> {
  return new Observable<number>((subscriber) => {
    let lastValue: number | undefined = undefined;
    let highestSpikedPercentChangeAbsOfLastSpikeWave: number | undefined =
      undefined;
    const previousValueAndTimeList: IValueAndTime[] = [];

    const subscription = value$
      .pipe(
        tap({
          next: (currentValue) => {
            const currentTime = new Date();

            removeOldValues(
              new Date(currentTime.getTime() - spikeIntervalMs),
              previousValueAndTimeList,
            );

            if (previousValueAndTimeList.length !== 0) {
              const maxPercentChangeAbs = Math.max(
                ...previousValueAndTimeList.map((previousValueAndTime) =>
                  Math.abs(
                    getPercentChangeAbs(
                      previousValueAndTime.value,
                      currentValue,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              );

              // todo decide if we should use `>=` or `>`
              if (maxPercentChangeAbs > spikePercentage) {
                if (
                  highestSpikedPercentChangeAbsOfLastSpikeWave !== undefined
                ) {
                  if (
                    maxPercentChangeAbs >
                    highestSpikedPercentChangeAbsOfLastSpikeWave
                  ) {
                    subscriber.next(maxPercentChangeAbs);
                    highestSpikedPercentChangeAbsOfLastSpikeWave =
                      maxPercentChangeAbs;
                  } else {
                    // todo confirm this logic
                    // We already showed user higher spike of this spike wave,
                    // so there is no need to show smaller spike
                  }
                } else {
                  subscriber.next(maxPercentChangeAbs);
                  highestSpikedPercentChangeAbsOfLastSpikeWave =
                    maxPercentChangeAbs;
                }
              } else {
                highestSpikedPercentChangeAbsOfLastSpikeWave = undefined;
              }
            } else {
              if (lastValue !== undefined) {
                const percentChangeAbs = getPercentChangeAbs(
                  lastValue,
                  currentValue,
                );

                // todo decide if we should use `>=` or `>`
                if (percentChangeAbs > spikePercentage) {
                  if (
                    highestSpikedPercentChangeAbsOfLastSpikeWave !== undefined
                  ) {
                    if (
                      percentChangeAbs >
                      highestSpikedPercentChangeAbsOfLastSpikeWave
                    ) {
                      subscriber.next(percentChangeAbs);
                      highestSpikedPercentChangeAbsOfLastSpikeWave =
                        percentChangeAbs;
                    } else {
                      // todo confirm this logic
                      // We already showed user higher spike of this spike wave,
                      // so there is no need to show smaller spike
                    }
                  } else {
                    subscriber.next(percentChangeAbs);
                    highestSpikedPercentChangeAbsOfLastSpikeWave =
                      percentChangeAbs;
                  }
                } else {
                  highestSpikedPercentChangeAbsOfLastSpikeWave = undefined;
                }
              } else {
                // todo decide what to do if we have first value
              }
            }

            previousValueAndTimeList.push({
              time: currentTime,
              value: currentValue,
            });
            lastValue = currentValue;
          },
          error: subscriber.error,
          complete: subscriber.complete,
        }),
      )
      .subscribe();

    return subscription;
  });
}

function getPercentChangeAbs(
  previousValue: number,
  currentValue: number,
): number {
  // todo consider changing this logic, depending on if value increased or decreased,
  //  and consider dividing by `previousValue` instead of `currentValue`
  //  if we need percentage compared to previous value
  return Math.abs(((currentValue - previousValue) / currentValue) * 100);
}

function removeOldValues(
  oldTime: Date,
  valueAndTimeList: IValueAndTime[],
): void {
  // todo make it use `LinkedList` to improve performance
  valueAndTimeList.splice(
    0,
    valueAndTimeList.length,
    ...valueAndTimeList.filter(
      // todo decide if we should use `>=` or `>`
      (valueAndTime) => valueAndTime.time >= oldTime,
    ),
  );
}

export interface IValueAndTime {
  time: Date;
  value: number;
}
```

Comment: All these RXJS solutions were so long, and I couldn't get something readily functional, so I added my own work-around solution that works perfectly :)